# Ruby param is missing or the value is empty: group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing an app with Ruby on Rails. Here is my controller action:

```
def new
@group = current_user.groups.build(group_params)
if @group.save
  flash[:success] = "Group created!"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  @feed_items = []
  render 'static_pages/home'
end
end
```

My form:

```
<%= form_for(@group) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :name, placeholder: "Group's name" %>
    <%= f.text_area :hashtag, placeholder: "Category" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

When I try to use:

```
private

    def group_params
      params.require(:group).permit(:name, :hashtag)
    end
```

I get the following exception:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: group
```

I've tried to change :group in require but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: your params doesn't have any key named `group`, post your params in the question

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I didn't understand, what do you mean with posting my params in the question?

Comment: Do you have form to submit? You will see some hash in the server log  when you hit the submit button. Please update the question with that hash

Comment: @Pavan I am trying to display the form but the exception is shown before I can hit the submit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> param is missing or the value is empty: group
>
> I am trying to display the form but the exception is shown before I
> can hit the submit button

Well then you are calling `group_params` in the *wrong method*. You should call it in `create` method. Let me clear up your code which should resolve your problem.

```
def new
  @group = current_user.groups.build
end

def create
  @group = current_user.groups.build(group_params)
  if @group.save
    flash[:success] = "Group created!"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    @feed_items = []
    render 'static_pages/home'
  end
end

private
def group_params
  params.require(:group).permit(:name, :hashtag)
end
```

***Explanation to the error:***

If you see the `params` hash while displaying the form you won't see any  `:group` key. Since you are calling `group_params` in the `new` method, the [*require*](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) *will raise an exception when the key is not present*,so is the error.

Comment: You got this (y). and see @Aldo, it very much helps.. :)

Comment: @Pavan OMG! It wokrs!! Thank you a lot!! Can u explain to me a little bit why my code was not working? I'm kind of new with Rails.

Comment: @Aldo If you see the `params` hash while displaying the form you won't see any any `:group` key. Since you are calling `group_params` in the `new` method and the [*require*](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) will *raise an exception when the key is not present*,so is the error. And by convention you should call such method(called as [*strong params*](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)) in `create` method for creating a record not in the `new` method. Hope you understood :)